# ObjectDeletedException: Why can't NHibernate break the association automatically?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a one-to-one mapping which I'm trying to express with Fluent NHibernate mappings. I know there are a LOT of similar questions/answers on the web but after hours I'm struggling to find an answer to my specific question.

I have a `Member` and `Subscription` object. 
A member can have 0..1 Subscriptions and a subscription instance can only ever pertain to a single member.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Member
{
    public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}

public class Subscription
{
    public Member Member { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my mappings (fluent):

For Member:

```
mapping.HasOne(member => member.Subscription)
    .PropertyRef(subscription => subscription.Member).Cascade.SaveOrUpdate();
```

For Subscription:

```
mapping.References(subscription => subscription.Member)
   .Unique().Cascade.None();
```

There are a few requirements but I can't seem to fulfill them all:

- That saving a `Member` cascades to `Subscription`.
- Deleting a `Subscription` breaks the association on the `Member`.
- Deleting a `Subscription` doesn't delete the `Member`.

If I set Cascade on `Member` the `Subscription` is saved, but deleting a `Subscription` throws an `ObjectDeletedException`.

*Why can't NHibernate automatically remove the association to `Subscription` first, before applying the cascade on `Member`?*

Comment: Isn't what you're looking for `Cascade.DeleteAllOrphans` on member subscriptions? Then setting member's Subscription to Null should remove the subscription from the DB.  Though if you're looking to do something like `Session.Delete(subscription)` then you have to set the member's subscription to #null anyways.

Comment: I'd like it to work both ways. In the case of the latter, I was wondering why NHibernate couldn't just remove that association for me?

Comment: NHibernate is not indented to change your member.Subscription just because some other code does session.Delete(sameSubscriptionInstance).

Comment: Why not? Isn't calling session.Delete(subscription) doing that implicitly anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is that this isn't a one-to-one relationship, it's a one-to-many with the many side constrained to 0 or 1. In a one-to-one relationship both entities must have the same primary key and this clearly isn't the case here. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208796/modeling-one-to-zero-or-one-relationships-z-cardinality).

I would model this as

```
public class Member
{
    private ICollection<Subscription> _subscriptions;

    public Name() { _subscriptions = new HashSet<Subscription>(); }

    public Subscription Subscription
    {
        get { return _subscriptions.SingleOrDefault(); }
        set
        {
            _subscriptions.Clear(); // may want to check if it contains value first
            value.Member = this; // assuming bidirectional association
            _subscriptions.Add(value); // null check value first
        }
    }
}

mapping.HasMany<Subscription>(Reveal.Member<Member>("_subscriptions"))
    .KeyColumn("MemberId")
    .AsSet().Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Also, I don't think you're using property-ref appropriately but that may be because you were mapping a one-to-one inappropriately.

Comment: Seriously, I can't thank you enough. This fulfills all of the requirements. I formulated the original mappings after looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160324/nhibernate-bi-directional-one-to-one-mapping-problem and the links posted in that answer. My next question is - how long does it take to garner this level of understanding of NHibernate?? :p

Comment: You're welcome. Answering questions on SO is one of the best ways to gain and maintain expertise and that's become my main motivation after I discovered that my points cannot be redeemed for valuable prizes. I've been working with NHibernate for 5 years and definitely have more to learn. One of the things I have learned is that true one-to-one relationships rarely exist and I've never used one in a real app.